# Get All Records of Monday from Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I am wondering if its possible to get all the records from a table which has a date created column return all those records whose day is monday based on date using linqtosql or linq? How to achieve this.

```
var callRecords =
                    mCallCompletionsQueryable.Where(
                        x =>
                        x.DateCreatedUTC.Value.Date.ToString("dddd") == "Monday").ToList();
```

Comment: Did you try anything? Some piece of code or..

Comment: the code throws error of no supported toString() at SQL

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
var mondayRecords = ctx.SomeTable.Where(
       row => row.SomeDateField.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday);
```

?